# (Discord.py) Setting up log?

Tags: python, logging, bots, discord.py

This is my first time here so please be patient with me XD.

Alright, I wanted to implement a logging system into my bot's `py` file, but I don't know how to start. I'm a beginner with discord.py. Do you have any tips how can I set it up by myself? (The Discord.py API could be a solution but sometimes I don't know how to use it "properly").

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your code? Can you review the stackoverflow guide on how to create a minimum reproducible example. So we can help you better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Unfortunately I only look in the internet for possible codes but I didn't found what I actually were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is events, [refer here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=invite#event-reference)

You can use an event listener to catch those events
(cog example)

```
  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message_delete(self, message):

        deleted = Embed(
            description=f"Message deleted in {message.channel.mention}", color=0x4040EC
        ).set_author(name=message.author, url=Embed.Empty, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)

        deleted.add_field(name="Message", value=message.content)
        deleted.timestamp = message.created_at
        await channel.send(embed=deleted)
```

If you're doing it in the main file, replace the decorator with `@bot.event()`
Similarly there are events for message send, message delete, edit, role add etc...

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that it doesn't react. Do I forgot a special `import`? Is it supposed to send the `deleted message` notification to the channel where the message got deleted?

Comment: EDIT: I get `on_message_delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'`

Comment: @malekmaroc7 It takes the parameter `message`, like `on_message_delete(message) ` if it's in a bot file, when using it in a cog add `self` before the `message`
Also, you should set a logging channel using `channel=bot.get_channel(channel_id)`

Comment: I get `NameError: name Embed is not defined`

Comment: @malekmaroc7 you import Embed from discord module: `from discord import Embed`.
Read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)